# variable decimal places in .Net string formatters?

Tags: .net, string-formatting

Fixed decimal places is easy

```
String.Format("{0:F1}", 654.321);
```

gives

```
654.3
```

How do I feed the number of decimal places in as a parameter like you can in C? 
So

```
String.Format("{0:F?}", 654.321, 2);
```

gives

```
654.32
```

I can't find what should replace the ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `NumberFormatInfo`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalDigits = 2 }, "{0:F}", new decimal(1234.567)));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalDigits = 7 }, "{0:F}", new decimal(1234.5)));
```

Comment: Thanks! Just learned something I didn't know.You might be better off using `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Clone()` to preserve the rest of the current cultureInfo.

Answer (score 23):

The string to format doesn't have to be a constant.

```
int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2;
string formatString = String.Concat("{0:F", numberOfDecimalPlaces, "}");
String.Format(formatString, 654.321);
```

Comment: Urgh! I thought this might be the answer. An extra string concat for every format seems horrible, but it's either that or write my own formatter I guess. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using interpolated strings like this:

```
int prec = 2;
string.Format($"{{0:F{prec}}}", 654.321);
```

Still a mess, but yet more convenient IMHO. Notice that string interpolation [replaces double braces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#special-characters), like `{{`, with a single brace.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient approach for formatting a single value:

```
int decimalPlaces= 2;
double value = Math.PI;
string formatString = String.Format("F{0:D}", decimalPlaces);
value.ToString(formatString);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an *interpolated string* approach similar to Wolfgang's answer, but a bit more compact and readable (IMHO):

```
using System.Globalization;
using NF = NumberFormatInfo;

...

decimal size = 123.456789;  
string unit = "MB";
int fracDigs = 3;

// Some may consider this example a bit verbose, but you have the text, 
// value, and format spec in close proximity of each other. Also, I believe 
// that this inline, natural reading order representation allows for easier 
// readability/scanning. There is no need to correlate formats, indexes, and
// params to figure out which values go where in the format string.
string s = $"size:{size.ToString("N",new NF{NumberDecimalDigits=fracDigs})} {unit}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I used two interpolated strings (a variant of [Michael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7108850/variable-decimal-places-in-net-string-formatters/58191480#58191480)):

```
double temperatureValue = 23.456;
int numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2;

string temperature = $"{temperatureValue.ToString($"F{numberOfDecimalPlaces}")} \u00B0C";
```

Answer (score 0):

Another [Fixed-point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#FFormatString) format with short [interpolated string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation) variant:

```
var value = 654.321;
var decimals = 2;

var s = value.ToString($"F{decimals}");
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the custom numeric format string [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
var value = 654.321;
var s = value.ToString("0.##");
```

Answer (score -3):

use

```
string.Format("{0:F2}", 654.321);
```

Output will be

> 654.32